# Implement a "universal" PHP (mysql) fetch row method (and assoc, and object)

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fetch

After several attempts to find a **unique** solution for my thought, I've had no chances to post this question here in the hope to find someone who can enlight me (if applicable).

I'm working on a "full featured" PHP class with several methods so I will be able to do what I'm willing to do in the future (that is, kinda of personal framework).

I'm stuck in the `fetchRow()` method of the class. I would like to use this method to fetch rows from a query AND I would like that this method automatically forms the proper data structure.

Now, assuming that I have a query like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM people", $dbHandle);
```

I would like to have this result (if applicable):

```
/*
 * var_dump example results after launching a while statement with
 * mysql_fetch_row.
 *
 * 2 fields (name,surname), 2 "master" arrays with corresponding values
 *
 */

array
 0 = array( ...names... )
 1 = array( ...surnames... )
```

Now, I tried several native PHP functions, user-defined functions, etc, without goals.

Maybe I'm crazy after these attempts, maybe this is not possible or maybe I can't see a possible simple way to do that.

How can I do that?

Comment: You aren't trying to re-invent Doctrine, are you? http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: Why don't you just use an ORM system?  Like Doctrine? http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

Comment: Thanks guys for your fast reply. No, I didn't even know Doctrine before now. I want to do that on my own. But of course thanks for your suggestion and links.

Comment: What do you mean by "_universal_ PHP (mysql) fetch row method"?

Comment: @Lèse a single method that perform an operation without need to re-type every time the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you would just do something like:

```
$data = array();
while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   foreach($row as $key => $value) {
      if(!isset($data[$key]) {
         $data[$key] = array();
      }

      $data[$key][] = $value;
   }
}
```

That said...

1. Just use Doctrine - either the full ORM or the DBAL.
2. Dont use `ext/mysql` use `PDO` or `Mysqli`.

Comment: Ok, I definitely was blind. That's the right point. Thanks @prodigitalson . But your solutions gives two master arrays (that's ok) with an internal array..with values. I want only these master arrays with values..no keys.

Comment: Well they key is jsut going to be the integer index of the column, so its analagous to jsut pushing onto the array. youll get results like: `$data[0][0] = 'Name0'` `$data[1][0] = 'Surname0'`... which is exactly what you asked for. The trik is to fetch the columns indexes (`mysql_fetch_array`) as keys instead of the column name (`mysql_fetch_assoc`)

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to have:
`array
  0 => array('Bob','Jack','Daniel', ... )
  1 => array('Nickelsen','Bibidi','Bobidi', ...)
`
...instead of...`array
  0 => array( 0 => 'Bob', 1 => 'Jack', 2 => 'Daniel', ... )
  1 => array( 0 => 'Nickelsen', 1 => 'Bibidi', 2 => 'Bobidi', ...)
`

Comment: And that is exactly what you will get... the arrays always have keys... `array('Value')` is EXACTLY the same as `array( 0 =>'Value')`. There is no such thing as a keyless array.

Comment: No, this is just wrong. Importing unbounded data sets into PHP arrays will cause frequent memory overflows and the performance will be APALLING.

Comment: Perfromance will be ugly, but i dont know that that deserves a downvote... It does exactly what he asked for however misguided that is... personally i dont even know why one would want a result set sorted in to arrays of values for each column... seems like the least useful way to structure a dataset.

Comment: Ok. That said, that read, I've modified a bit @prodig's snippet and I think this can suit my needs for now. Thanks to you all ;)